# JAVA: TCP readline() termination, binary zero

Tags: java, tcp

I am trying to receive TCP data from a 3rd party server, whose messages are terminated with a binary zero (`'\0'`) rather than newline (`'\n`). From what I understand, JAVA's `readline()` waits for an `'\n'` termination, which might be the reason that my code hangs.

```
try {
    socket = new Socket(hostip, portNum);
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
    msg = inFromServer.readLine();
    socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        msg = "Connection failed. IOException.";
    }
```

Is there a way to read a message from the server, such that `'\0'` will denote the end of transmission rather than `'\n'`?

Thanks

Comment: A line is terminated by a line terminator,  by definition. A *C string* is terminated by a null.

Answer (score 2):

Just use directly the `InputStreamReader`:

```
    try {
        socket = new Socket(hostip, portNum);
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int ch = 'a';

        while((ch = in.read()) != (char)0){
            if(ch == -1) break;
            System.out.println(ch);
            sb.append((char)ch);
        }

        msg = sb.toString();
        socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            msg = "Connection failed. IOException.";
        }
```